# WCF4 REST APIkey question - pass information from ServiceAuthorizationManager to services

Tags: wcf, restful-authentication, api-key

I want to implement an API key authentication solution for my WCF4 REST API.

I know that I need to make a class and derive it from ServiceAuthorizationManager and override the CheckAccessCore method. All that I understand.

But what I want to do from the CheckAccessCore pass internal information from the CheckAccessCore to my Service implementation classes. Information like "ApiKeyID, rights, flags and other details" that I looked up when doing the ApiKey authentication.

So that my services internally can use the internal ApiKeyID when it calls the domain logic.

I have seen many different ways of doing this, like

```
operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.Properties["Principal"] = p;
```

or

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

and other ways....

Comment: I have this same question, except I'm using WCF Data Services. Did you ever find a good answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can pass along objects is by adding the object to the Properties Collection of the RequestMessage object.

```
IssuedToken Token = new IssuedToken() 
operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties.Add("NameOfObj",Token);
```

Comment: Ok, that's how you set it, but how do you you retrieve it? WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest doesn't have properties as far as I can tell. Only headers.

Comment: I don't think operationContext is available to REST. Just WebOperationContext, which only has HTTP headers.

Comment: I build REST WCF and used the above technique to pass data from my ServiceAuthorizationManager to my other code.

Comment: Victor, would you mind flushing out your code example then? I am especially interested in seeing how you retrieve the object from your WebGet calls in the main .svc.cs file.